# JPA: PersistenceException "unknown state or association field"

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I am trying to understand how to do (simple) joins in JPQL.  I have two tables/entities: Parent and Child.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Parent.findByStatus", query = "SELECT p FROM Parent p WHERE p.status = :status")})
public class Parent
{
    private String parentId;
    private Set<Child> children;
    private String status;

    public Parent()
    {
        // empty constructor
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
    public String getParentId()
    {
        return parentId;
    }

    public void setParentId(String parentId)
    {
        this.parentId= parentId;
    }

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Child
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    public Set<Child> getChildren()
    {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildre(Set<Child> children)
    {
        this.children= children;
    }
    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    public String getStatus()
    {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }
}

@Entity
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Child.findByStatus", query = "SELECT c FROM Child c WHERE c.status = :status"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Child.findByParentId", query = "SELECT c FROM Child c JOIN c.parent p WHERE p.parentId = :parentId"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Child.findByParentIdAndStatus", query = "SELECT c FROM Child c JOIN c.parent p WHERE p.parentId = :parentId AND c.status = :status") })
public class Child
{
    private childId id;
    private String status;
    private Parent parent;

    public Child()
    {
        // empty constructor
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CHILD_ID")
    public String getChildId()
    {
        return childId;
    }

    public void setChildId(String childId)
    {
        this.childId= childId;
    }

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to Parent 
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    public Parent getParent ()
    {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent)
    {
        this.parent= parent;
    }

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    public String getStatus()
    {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

But this causes the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-8030] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Error compiling the query [Child.findByParentId: SELECT c FROM Child c JOIN c.parent p WHERE p.parentId = :parentId], line 1, column 47: unknown state or association field [parentId] of class [my.model.Parent].
```

It's my understanding that JPQL traverses the object model on JOINs.  So, in the query:

```
SELECT c FROM Child c JOIN c.parent p WHERE p.parentId = :parentId
```

`p` is the fetched Parent object associated with the Child objects.  If this is correct, then why I am getting the error?  The Parent object has a parentId field and so should be okay, yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JPQL looks valid.  Check that you compiled your code correctly, (did you recently rename the field?).

Does querying any of the other fields work?  What if you rename the field to id?

Comment: I'm using Maven to do my builds. The entity classes are built into a jar library which is used by my test servlet.  I have cleaned and rebuilt both projects multiples times including manually wiping out the entity library from the repo to ensure it's the latest one used in the servlet war.  I am deploying to Glassfish v3.1.1 and I have tried undeploying and redeploying the war.  So, I'm pretty sure that the code is compile correctly. This is sooo frustrating as all the examples I've seen of JPQL indicate my query is correct.

Comment: If I comment out the queries in Child that have joins to Parent, I can successfully execute the "Parent.findByStatus" query.  So, there must be something wrong with my joins.  Sigh....

Comment: and try field access instead of property, then the name is more obvious

Comment: The root of the issue was in the naming of the variables versus the methods with slight differences in capitalization between the two (e.g. `parentID` versus `getParentId` - the 'd' being different).  In the query I was using the variable capitalization and EclipseLink was looking for the method name version.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the fields of Child to achive this,

```
from Child c where c.parent.id = :parent_id
```

or just if you have a reference to a parent at hand and not just the id.

```
from Child c where c.parent = :parent
```

hibernate will figure out the join itself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I don't have an object reference to the parent, so can't use the second one.  The first one results in the same error.  :(  BTW, I'm not using Hibernate, but EclipseLink.